# Is it possible to get the boundary of X and Y coordinates given fixed Z in libgdx

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx

I know it possible to use PerspectiveCamera's frustum member to judge if a point(x,y,z) is in the frustum by calling pointInFrustum(Vector3 point) function.  Now if the z-coordinate is fixed to some value, can I get the boundary of x and y axis that is visible directly?

Comment: For what reason you want the boundaries at arbitrary z for a frustum? Sounds like you should use an orthographic camera, not a perspective one.

Comment: But I need to show 3D models, so PerspectiveCamera is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The [Frustum](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.java) contains the 8 points (`planePoints`) making up the near and far plane:

```
/** eight points making up the near and far clipping "rectangles". order is counter clockwise, starting at bottom left **/
public final Vector3[] planePoints
```

These points are updated when `Camera.update` is called. To be on the safe side, just call this once before doing the following operations:

1. Calculate a parameter `t` (in `[0,1]`) specifying how far the POI is away from the near plane wrt the far plane.
2. `t` allows to linearly interpolate the *top surface* of the frustum (unsure about how to call this) down the `z` axis.

---

*And btw, `frustum` in libgdx's `Camera` class should really be called something like `viewvolume`, since orthographic projections don't span a frustum in space.*